# Not to display DataTextField value in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Really silly question but it's really frustrating me.

Inside my gridview I have DataTextField and also a field for Text

```
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="hotelId" HeaderText="View Hotel" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="View" />
```

At the moment when I display results that are binded, the hotelId get replaced with values inside the array. On the front end instead of displaying all those values I just want to display 'View' as suggested in the `Text="View"`.

I've tried everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to be View do not provide a `DataTextField`. It's as simple as that.